# Calculating the time spent with dates and time format in r

Tags: r, time

I am working on a time/date variable and trying to estimate the time spent for each record. I am following two steps for this analysis. 
`(a)` modify the variables in the desired format
`(b)` calculate the time spent on each question.
Here how my dataset looks like:

```
id <-     c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2)
item.id <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5)
submit.time <-c("2019-04-09 09:50:30.340","2019-04-09 09:52:12.440","2019-04-09 09:52:15.787","2019-04-09 09:53:21.587","2019-04-09 09:53:49.047",
                "2019-04-09 09:49:45.243","2019-04-09 09:52:53.663","2019-04-09 09:53:23.293","2019-04-09 09:54:00.727","2019-04-09 09:54:52.400")
start.time <- c("04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM","04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM","04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM","04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM","04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM",
                "04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM","04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM","04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM","04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM","04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM")

data <- data.frame(id, item.id,start.time, submit.time)

> data
   id item.id                 start.time             submit.time
1   1       1 04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM 2019-04-09 09:50:30.340
2   1       2 04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM 2019-04-09 09:52:12.440
3   1       3 04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM 2019-04-09 09:52:15.787
4   1       4 04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM 2019-04-09 09:53:21.587
5   1       5 04/09/2019 09:50:02.317 AM 2019-04-09 09:53:49.047
6   2       1 04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM 2019-04-09 09:49:45.243
7   2       2 04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM 2019-04-09 09:52:53.663
8   2       3 04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM 2019-04-09 09:53:23.293
9   2       4 04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM 2019-04-09 09:54:00.727
10  2       5 04/09/2019 09:47:42.583 AM 2019-04-09 09:54:52.400
```

`id` for each student, `item.id` is the id of the question, `start.time` is the for login time to the exam(unique time for each student), and `submit.time` is the time when a student submits the answer for each question.

`(a)` editing data: this step includes removing `AM|PM` and switching the order of the `start.time` because I would like to use the `submit.time`'s format, and edited `start.time`'s format.

```
data$start.time <- gsub(" AM| PM", "", data$start.time) # exclude AM or PM
data$start.time <- gsub("/", "-", data$start.time) #replace / with -
dtparts = t(as.data.frame(strsplit(data$start.time,' '))) # split date and time
row.names(dtparts) = NULL
data$newdate <- strptime(as.character(dtparts[,1]), "%m-%d-%Y") # switch the date order
data$newdate <- as.POSIXct(data$newdate) # R was complaining about the time format-had to change here
data$start.time <- paste0(data$newdate," ",dtparts[,2]) # bring the time back
```

Now, the two-timing variables look the same. I transformed these dates and times to seconds.

```
data %>%
  mutate(start.time.num = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(start.time), units="secs"))  %>%
  mutate(submit.time.num = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(submit.time), units="secs"))

   id item.id              start.time             submit.time    newdate start.time.num submit.time.num
1   1       1 2019-04-09 09:50:02.317 2019-04-09 09:50:30.340 2019-04-09     1554817802      1554817830
2   1       2 2019-04-09 09:50:02.317 2019-04-09 09:52:12.440 2019-04-09     1554817802      1554817932
3   1       3 2019-04-09 09:50:02.317 2019-04-09 09:52:15.787 2019-04-09     1554817802      1554817936
4   1       4 2019-04-09 09:50:02.317 2019-04-09 09:53:21.587 2019-04-09     1554817802      1554818002
5   1       5 2019-04-09 09:50:02.317 2019-04-09 09:53:49.047 2019-04-09     1554817802      1554818029
6   2       1 2019-04-09 09:47:42.583 2019-04-09 09:49:45.243 2019-04-09     1554817663      1554817785
7   2       2 2019-04-09 09:47:42.583 2019-04-09 09:52:53.663 2019-04-09     1554817663      1554817974
8   2       3 2019-04-09 09:47:42.583 2019-04-09 09:53:23.293 2019-04-09     1554817663      1554818003
9   2       4 2019-04-09 09:47:42.583 2019-04-09 09:54:00.727 2019-04-09     1554817663      1554818041
10  2       5 2019-04-09 09:47:42.583 2019-04-09 09:54:52.400 2019-04-09     1554817663      1554818092
```

`(b)` in this step, I would like to calculate the time spent on each question here. For the first question of the first student, the time spent should be `submit.time.num(1554817830) - start.time.num(1554817802)=28`. For the second question of the first student, the time spent should be `submit.time.num(1554817932)` `-` previous `submit.time.num(1554817830)=102`. This procedure needs to be repeated for each student. When it gets to the second student, it should take the `start.time` again for the first row of the second student.

So, the additional column should look like this:

```
> time.spent
   time.spent
1          28
2         102
3           4
4          66
5          27
6         122
7         189
8          29
9          38
10         51
```

I apologize for posting this long, if you also have any suggestions for the first part, please let me know, more importantly, any suggestions for the part `(b)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done a bit faster in a single pipeline.

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(
    start.time = as.POSIXct(start.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS"),
    submit.time = as.POSIXct(submit.time),
    time.spent = difftime(submit.time, start.time, units = "secs")
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    time.spent = c(time.spent[1], diff(time.spent))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#       id item.id start.time          submit.time         time.spent  
#    <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>      
#  1     1       1 2019-04-09 09:50:02 2019-04-09 09:50:30  28.023 secs
#  2     1       2 2019-04-09 09:50:02 2019-04-09 09:52:12 102.100 secs
#  3     1       3 2019-04-09 09:50:02 2019-04-09 09:52:15   3.347 secs
#  4     1       4 2019-04-09 09:50:02 2019-04-09 09:53:21  65.800 secs
#  5     1       5 2019-04-09 09:50:02 2019-04-09 09:53:49  27.460 secs
#  6     2       1 2019-04-09 09:47:42 2019-04-09 09:49:45 122.660 secs
#  7     2       2 2019-04-09 09:47:42 2019-04-09 09:52:53 188.420 secs
#  8     2       3 2019-04-09 09:47:42 2019-04-09 09:53:23  29.630 secs
#  9     2       4 2019-04-09 09:47:42 2019-04-09 09:54:00  37.434 secs
# 10     2       5 2019-04-09 09:47:42 2019-04-09 09:54:52  51.673 secs
```

Using @akrun's suggestion, we can shorten the code a little:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    start.time = as.POSIXct(start.time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS"),
    submit.time = as.POSIXct(submit.time),
    time.spent = submit.time - lag(submit.time, default = first(start.time))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(and optionally remove the columns you no longer need).

Comment: Didn't saw your solution.  Will delete mine (sorry, vote limit reached). You could add `transmute(time.spent = submit.time.num - 
            lag(submit.time.num, default = first(start.time.num)))`

Comment: @akrun "vote limit reached"? Huh ... perhaps I need to vote more, I've never seen that alert. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353868/how-to-improve-daily-vote-limit-reached-situation)